# Teradata Stored Procedure Insert data example

Tags: teradata

I have created a simple stored procesdure to insert values into dbc.AlertREquest table.

Do I need to write any exception handling logic for simple inserting values into a table.

I mean do I need to write the Exception Handling for Insert data not successful. In that case what kind of SQLSTATE do I need to write.

Please let me know.

Please see the sample code below.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE XXXXXXXXX.ALERT_REQUEST_INSERT( IN p_JobName character(60),
                                                                                                                                      IN p_JobDescription character(120),
                                                                                                                                        IN p_ActionDestination character(120), 
                                                                                                                                        IN p_JobFullMessage character(600))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbcmngr.AlertRequest
                    ( 
                       AlertRequest.ReqDate,
                       AlertRequest.ReqTime,
                       AlertRequest.JobName,
                       AlertRequest.Description,
                       AlertRequest.EventValue,
                       AlertRequest.ActionCode,
                       AlertRequest.RepeatPeriod,
                       AlertRequest.Destination,
                       AlertRequest.Message
                   )
      VALUES    
                   (
                      DATE,
                      TIME,
                      : p_JobName,
                      : p_JobDescription,
                       0,
                       '+',
                       0,
                       : p_ActionDestination,
                       : p_JobFullMessage
                 );
   END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    insert into your_trace_table(message) values (:SQLSTATE);
  END;
  -- your insert goes here
END;
```